# Is it possible to extract style information from GeoJson for an openlayers javascript map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I have a geojson file structured like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "marker-color": "#4620dd",
        "marker-size": "medium",
        "marker-symbol": "park",
        "name": "State Park"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-76.95266723632812,
            39.07974903895123
        ]
    }
}]
```

}

I am able to create a vector layer from this geojson in an openlayers map, but unable to utilize the styling properties. Should I use a custom style function to do this?

Comment: Yes, you should use a ol.style to style your layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for sure:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: function (feature, resolution) {
    console.log(feature.getProperties()); // <== all geojson properties
    return [new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: feature.get('marker-color') })
      })
    })];
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/uvopawmg/